# How to avoid DLL Main?

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, reverse-engineering, dllmain

I have asked this before, although people ignored it. Then again it was a lengthy topic, therefore I'll try to keep this shorter.

When you Inject a DLL into a program you do not own, how can you avoid using DLL Main? A lot of you may know that when you are using a thread for example in DLL main, it will simply cause a program halt (in most cases).

I would really like to know the best way to actually get a thread running from a Injected DLL without putting it in DLL Main... which to me seems impossible as I don't know how.

I know you can put a compiled .dll which the program has to load inside the folder, however it isn't the real DLL for example DirectX, and load the DLLs required there however I am currently doing this and it means controlling my program through a DirectX hack. Which someone has already injected into another program (according to MySQL debug logs). I know this can be done anyway with an Injector but it would be harder.

Does anyone know of a way, as I could kill for one right now?

EDIT: To this thread being a duplicate, it isn't I already use this inject my DLL.

```
int InjectDLL(HANDLE Handle, const char* Path)
{
    void *Lib, *String;
    Lib = (void*)(LoadLibraryA);
    String = (void*)VirtualAllocEx(Handle, NULL, strlen(Path), MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    WriteProcessMemory(Handle, (void*)String, Path, strlen(Path), NULL);
    CreateRemoteThread(Handle, NULL, NULL, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Lib, (void*)String, NULL, NULL);
    return true;
}
```

however using DllMain in the Injected DLL will cause a system halt as I have reached a point where it's too much.

I need a way to prevent the system halt, and possibly create the thread outside of DLLMain, for example maybe a way to start a thread of a DLL without having to use the DLLMain in the DLL I have injected.

Comment: What do you know about the process you are injecting into? One way is to temporarily hijack a routine in the process that you know will be called by poking a jump into it that goes to your DLL code where you then launch your thread (you'll need to save off what you overwrite so that you can restore it). -- One approach that might work well would be to hijack an import thunk in the EXE for a DLL function. That should be fairly clean and low-risk in terms of potential corruption.

Comment: This makes no sense. Inject your DLL. Create a thread in its DllMain. Job done. If you fumbled the implementation and produced a program halt then fix the problem. But the problem is with your implementation rather than the technique.

Comment: I've injected d3d9.dll into a game before.. There's NO problems creating regular threads with `CreateThread` but using `std::thread` automatically halts the program. At least for me it does.. Perhaps it's something to do with MSVC because it works in g++. Just use `CreateThread` instead (for MSVC-2013)..